# how to RewriteRule https in php mvc

Tags: php, .htaccess

i am setting up https to my website but my mvc codes contradiction with RewriteRule https how to i merge them?

https :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

mvc:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^www. [NC]
 RewriteRule .* https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```